# GitHub authenticates as the wrong SSH user

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have 2 GitHub users, for work and personal.

Each has their own ssh key: the personal one happens to be id_rsa, and the work one is id_ed25519. Each key is associated with the correct account in GitHub.

When working on work stuff, I changed `~/.ssh/config` to use the work SSH key for everything (such as pushing to git@github.com):

```
UseRoaming no

Host *
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Now, I want to use my personal account again. I changed `IdentityFile` back to `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, but when I try to push changes to a repo it authenticates as the wrong user.

`git remote -v` shows nothing that would indicate using the work ssh key:

```
origin  git@github.com:redacted-user/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:redacted-user/repo.git (push)
```

`ssh git@github.com` is indeed authenticating as the wrong user:

```
Hi [work account]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

How is GitHub authenticating my user?

I've confirmed there are no specific entries for github.com in ssh config, and I've confirmed my id_rsa is linked in my personal GitHub account.

Comment: I have also confirmed using `ssh git@github.com -v` that it is matching the rule and using id_rsa. id_rsa is not associated with the account that is authenticated.

Comment: @phd Those links answer the question of using different GitHub accounts at the same time. They do not address my scenario. I did search before I posted.

Answer (score 1):

> How is GitHub authenticating my user

By the public key registered to the GitHub account, matching the private key used locally.

Try a ssh -Tv git@github.com to understand which private key is actually used.

I prefer changing the remote URL to make sure I am using one account or the other.

In my ~/.ssh/config file, I would register the second account as:

```
Host ghuser2
  User git
  hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/secondUserKey
```

Then:

```sh
ssh -T ghuser2
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote set-url origin ghuser2:<aUser>/<aRepo>
git ls-remote # for testing
```

Note that it does not change the *authorship* of the commits made in that repository.
If git config user.name is still `user1`, and you make new commits, those will be displayed on GitHub as `user1`, even if you authenticate (when pushing them) as `user2`.

Answer (score -2):

Need this after changing the ssh config:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```